# Finding the change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following question in an assignment and I don't know how to approach it, please see the image below for the question. Hopefully someone can help :) [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6Eh0.jpg)

[image]

Comment: You can post images directly here in the question. Also trying to type it with mathjax/latex is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let matrix $A$ be
\begin{bmatrix}
    3 & 0 \\
    4 & -1
\end{bmatrix}

Let matrix $B$ be
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1 \\
    4 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Your change of basis matrix from g to e would be:

$A\times B=$

\begin{bmatrix}
    3 & -3 \\
    0 & 5
\end{bmatrix}

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Multiply the given matrices in the appropriate order.